# Capacity of 2 BSCs

Tags: information-theory

I have a channel with input/output = $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and my transition matrix looks like:

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1-a & a & 0 & 0 \\
a & 1-a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1-b & b \\
0 & 0 & b & 1-b
\end{array}\right]$

I know that this is the combination / sum of two BSC, but my first problem is how to proof it.

The second one is that I want to calculate the capacity of the channel. I know that if I consider one BSC, the capacity would be $1 - H(a)$.

Let $X_1 = {0,1} = Y_1 $ and $X_2,Y_2$ analogously.
I already started like this:

$I(X;Y) = I(X_1, X_2;Y_1;Y_2) \\
 = H(Y_1,Y_2) + H(Y_1,Y_2|X_1,X_2) \\
 = H(Y_1) + H(Y_2) + H(Y_1,Y_2|X_1,X_2) \\
$

I can say that $H(Y_1,Y_2) = H(Y_1) + H(Y_2)$ because they are independent. However, I'm stuck here.

Comment: What is a BSC ?

Comment: $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are *not* independent in general since $X_1$ and $X_2$ may not be independent. However, for capacity calculation purposes, it may turn out that independent $X_1$, $X_2$ is indeed the capacity achieving input distribution.... Also, there is a wrong sign in the mutual information expansion.

Comment: I didn't understand oyour definition of $X_1,Y_1$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a combination of two paralell separable BSC "subchannels".

A standard trick for this kind of problem is to introduce an additional random variable that signals which of the two subchannels was used (say $Z=1$ if $X\in \{1,2\}$, $Z=2$ if $X\in \{3,4\}$). The key is that knowing $Y$ one knows $Z$. Hence  we write the chain rule for mutual information: $$I(X;Y,Z) = I(X;Y) + I(X;Z|Y) = I(X;Z) + I(X;Y|Z) $$

and we note that $I(X;Z|Y)=0$ (knowing $Y$, $Z$ is a constant). Further, letting $\alpha=P(Z=1)$: $$I(X;Z)=H(Z) - H(Z|X)=H(Z)=h(\alpha)$$ where $h(\cdot)$ is the binary entropy function, and 
$$I(X;Y|Z) = \alpha I(X_1;Y_1) + (1-\alpha)I(X_2;Y_2)$$
where $X_1,Y_1$ are the inputs and outputs of the first subchannel, and so on.

Then $$C=\max_{p(X)} I(X;Y)=\max_{\alpha,p{(X_1)},p{(X_2)}} h(\alpha)+\alpha I(X_1;Y_1) + (1-\alpha)I(X_2;Y_2)\\=\max_{\alpha} h(\alpha)+\alpha C_1 + (1-\alpha)C_2 $$

Maximizing over $\alpha$ we get the general formula for parallell (separable) channels: $2^C=2^C_1+2^C_2$

Comment: Nice derivation (+1). At first I thought the OP assumed that the two BSCs were used in parallel, however, this answer corresponds to the input alphabet and transition matrix stated in the question. It is interesting to note that even with $C_1=C_2=0$ a capacity of $1$ bit/channel use - as in the case of a single ideal BSC - can be achieved due to the "orthogonality" of the two BSCs

Comment: Thank you,  but why are you expressing $I(X;Z)$ and not $I(X;Y)$? Because you stated that $I(X;Z|Y) = 0$. Then it would make sense for me that $I(X;Y)$ is focused on. Also: Why is $H(Z|X) = 0?$? Isn't actually $H(X|Z) = H(Y|Z)$?

Comment: Why can you say that $I(X;Y|Z) = \alpha I(X_1;Y_1) + (1-\alpha)I(X_2;Y_2)$ so easily? Doesn't this need proof? It is intuitive...

Comment: First question: see my answer here (the idea is the same) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048164/fanos-inequality/2049053#2049053

Comment: Second question: $H(Z|X) = 0$ because knowing the value of $X$ you know $Z$

Comment: Third question: the (general) equation $I(X;Y|Z) =\sum_z p(Z=z) I(X;Y|Z=z)$ is the analogous of the one for conditional entropy ($H(X|Z)=\sum_z p(Z=z) H(X|Z=z)$. You can prove it if you don't know it. If you know it, then my equation comes directly.

Comment: Can you give hints on the proof for $I(X;Y|Z) = \sum_z p(Z=z) I(X;Y|Z=z)$?

Comment: Thank you, I understand everything now. The only thing where I am not sure is why one can simply say that $I(X;Z|Y) = 0$.

Comment: $I(X;Z|Y) =H(Z|Y) - H(Z|X,Y)$ Both entropies are zero, because knowing $Y$ you know $Z$

Comment: I just discovered this answer and have another question: In the last two lines, why can you just exchange $I(X_1; X_2)$ with $C_1$?